# Converting packets of binary to integers for ASCII

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am trying to iterate through packets of binary code. My input are text files with various amount of binary (some are just the eight digits and some are hundreds of digits. I packetized the binary into packets of 8. I am trying to write code that will iterate through the binary and where-ever a '1' is present, enumerate it with the corresponding integer(128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1). I can't figure out how to convert the binary or enumerate it.

I tried using int, however, I think that I am supposed to use a loop and when I used int it only converted the first eight digits and didn't do anything to the other packets.

I couldn't enumerate the binary code with the integer list. However, the expected result is that a text file will be read and the binary code will be packetized. The binary code will iterated through and the corresponding integer shall take place for the '1' in the binary. Then the integer/packets of integers will be converted to ASCII. Some text files (inputs) contain binary that translates to a single letter and other files have binary that translates the multiple sentences, so the amounts of packets differ.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do, because your Python code is syntactically incorrect in multiple ways, and the logic of it makes no sense either.  enumerate()'s second argument is an integer, not a list or tuple.  You're iterating over 'packets', but calling sum() on it repeatedly within the iteration, which makes no sense in and of itself.  sum() expects to sum lists of numbers, but you're passing it a list of strings.  In short, your code wouldn't run and makes no sense, so it's impossible to give you any guidance here.

Comment: Are you trying to turn strings of zeros and ones into ASCII?

Comment: That is the ultimate goal. Like I wrote before, I was able to packetize the binary code  into groups of eights. Now I have to go through those ones and zeros and convert it to integers based on where the ones are and that integer will be summed up for each packet that will then be translated into ASCII.

Comment: You could probably extend the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612781/2226988) from @Steve and skip your step that takes substrings of length  8.

Comment: I think you still need the packetization.  If you're assuming that the input is ascii, then you need to operate on character-sized (8-bit) chunks.  There isn't, however, any reason to break the logic into two loops.  Just pull of the next 8 characters, and immediately turn them into an 8-bit integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to turn 8 bit strings of zeros and ones into binary values:

```
def main():
    packets = ["11111111", "10000000", "00000100", "00000010", "00000001", "00000000"]
    ascii = []
    for packet in packets:
        acc = 0
        for i in range(0, 8):
            if packet[7-i] == '1':
                acc += 1 << i
        ascii.append(acc)
    print ascii
```

Result: 
[255, 128, 4, 2, 1, 0]

You can use the chr() function to turn ascii values into characters.  This line would take the resulting ascii value list from above and turn it into a list of characters:

```
chars = [chr(i) for i in ascii]
```

Given my example packets, you're going to get strange, unprintable characters.